# Factoring out common code when the common code has multiple incompatible return types

Tags: java, refactoring

I just stumbled over a weird piece of code while refactoring. It looks like a candidate for factoring out the common part of both readString()-methods, only it seems to be impossible (it's a freaking brain teaser for me):

```
private final StringBuilder readStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(128);

@Override
public String readString() throws IOException {
    final int l = readInt();
    if (l <= 0) {
        switch (l) {
            case -1: return null;
            case 0: return "";
            default: throw new IOException("invalid string length encoding: " + l);
        }
    }
    readStringBuilder.setLength(0);
    for (int i=0; i<l; ++i) {
        readStringBuilder.append(readChar());
    }
    return readStringBuilder.toString();
}

@Override
public String readString(final StringCache cache) throws IOException {
    final int l = readInt();
    if (l <= 0) {
        switch (l) {
            case -1: return null;
            case 0: return "";
            default: throw new IOException("invalid string length encoding: " + l);
        }
    }
    readStringBuilder.setLength(0);
    for (int i=0; i<l; ++i) {
        readStringBuilder.append(readChar());
    }
    return cache.get(readStringBuilder, readStringBuilder);
}
```

You see that both methods do *almost* the same, the method body is completely identical, except for the return statement. But since there are early termination exits, I can't find a method signature that can take the main body - natuarally the returns type would be StringBuilder, only in the early termination case it would be String...

Any ideas how to factor the body into a separate method? (and take note that toString() on an empty StringBuilder does *create* a new String instead of returning a constant string literal)

EDIT: Definition of the StringCache is:

```
public interface StringCache {
    public String get(final CharSequence charSeq, final CharSequence notFoundResult);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like having `readStringBuilder` as an instance field is some form of (premature?) optimization. Assuming this is the case, how about something like this:

```
private StringBuilder readStringHelper() throws IOException {
  StringBuilder readStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(128);
    final int l = readInt();
    if (l <= 0) {
        switch (l) {
            case -1: return null;
            case 0: break;
            default: throw new IOException("invalid string length encoding: " + l);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<l; ++i) {
        readStringBuilder.append(readChar());
    }
    return readStringBuilder;
}

@Override
public String readString() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder readStringBuilder = readStringHelper();
    return readStringBuilder==null ? null : readStringBuilder.toString();
}

@Override
public String readString(final StringCache cache) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder readStringBuilder = readStringHelper();
    return readStringBuilder== null ? null : cache.get(readStringBuilder, readStringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Seems I gave the same answer as Brian Agnew, but I needed more words... ;-)

Comment: The code belongs to a reader class (that wraps an input stream). I don't think it unreasonable that it does not create a new StringBuilder for each string it reads.

Comment: I think your approach is very clean, Brian Agnew basically suggested to factor out just reading the string content (the for loop) as I understood it. You thought a bit further than that.

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just create one private method that populates the `readStringBuilder` appropriately ?

Then both `readString()` methods use that, and either perform a `get()` on the cache, or a `toString()` on the `readStringBuilder` ?

It's worth considering this in the light of the *Composed Method* refactoring, which takes as a principle that:

> Composed method says that each method should do one and only one thing

and when you obey this, your methods often become reusable (composable).

> What have I achieved by going through this refactoring exercise? ....
>   now that I have small building blocks, method reuse becomes
>   easier because now I can mix and match them

See Neil Ford's article on the *Composed Method* refactoring [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-eaed4/index.html). See also Martin Fowler's '[extractMethod](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)' refactoring.

Comment: I can only accept one answer and Axel spotted the opportunity to turn the factored out return type into CharSequence. +1 anyway.